# Last contribution tokens

Tags: tokens, civirules

I am trying to create a rule that will notify our CEO of donations over a certain amount.  In the message template I want to include info about the donation.  I'm choosing the tokens for "latest contribution amount" and "latest contribution financial type" etc. but they are all blank when pulled into my email?

Comment: Are you using fuzion tokens?

Comment: @PradeepNayak yes it looks like we are, but it's running version 1.3

Comment: @PradeepNayak Do you think updating fuzion tokens will help resolve the issue?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion are you able to offer any advice?

Comment: I think it does, have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the Fuzion tokens extension to the latest release fixed the issue.